# Excel - extract values from multiple cells and list them

Tags: microsoft-excel, list

Let's say I'm a tutor. Each one of my students wrote the list of days in which they're avaliable. They wrote the days in a single cell next to their names in a table.

I'm looking for a formula, which would invert that listing - match and list the names next to the days.

Any ideas? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your data structure doesn't supports an Array formula to extract multiple value based on Criteria since Weekdays are in One Cell !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel or later then you can use TEXTJOIN as an Array Formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E4,$B$1:$B$3)),$A$1:$A$3,""))
```

Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This will iterate the values in `$B$1:$B$3` searching for the desired day name, if found it will return the name to the TEXTJOIN Function, if Not it returns a blank that is ignored by the TEXTJOIN Function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach

1 : Column Headings : Student, Schedule, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday

2: Enter Students Names in A2, A3, A4.. as A, B, C, D, etc… in Student Column

3: In Schedule Column For Student A write Schedule as "Monday, Tuesday,Friday" For student B write "Monday, Wednesday" For student C enter "Monday,Wednesday, Sat" etc..

4: For Monday Column Head Monday : In cell C2 : enter the formula as =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1,B2)),A2,"")

5 : Copy C2 in C3, C4…etc down the line for Monday Column
6 : In Tuesday : cell D2 enter the formula as =if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1,B2)),A2,"") and copy down the line

This way a result will be displayed Daywise, who are the students to be taught

Thanks.